# Initializing Python dictionary using dict() vs {}

Tags: python, variables, dictionary, reference

I am witnessing a very weird behviour with the following Python code snippet.

```
list_of_dict = [{}]*2                  # create a list of 2 dict
list_of_dict[0]["add_to_dict_0"] = 1   # add a (key,val) pair to 1st dict

print list_of_dict[0]
print list_of_dict[1]
```

The output is:

> {'add_to_dict_0': 1}
>
> {'add_to_dict_0': 1}

Both the dictionaries got updated, although I (explicitly) updated only one. However, changing the initialization in Line 1 to the following:

```
list_of_dict = [dict() for _ in xrange(0,2)]
```

fixes the issue.

What is the reason for this behaviour? I am guessing that this is an artefact of the concept of [name-object binding](http://python.net/%7Egoodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables) in Python (as opposed to variable-memory location binding in other languages like C/C++). My guess is that in the first case, both `list_of_dict[0]` and `list_of_dict[1]` are bound to the same dictionary object.

Is my suspicion correct? If yes, then why is the behaviour not replicated in the second case? What is the difference between `dict_object = dict()` and `dict_object = {}`?

Comment: Both `list_of_dict = [dict() for _ in xrange(0,2)]` and `list_of_dict = [{} for _ in xrange(0,2)]` work. Your question isn't actually about `dict()` vs `{}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference between **dict_object = dict()** and **dict_object = {}**

The problem here is **[{}] * 2** will generate a list with 2 elements which are reference to a single object. **[{} for x in range(2)]** will generate a list with two elements which are reference two distinct objects.

Replacing **{}** with **dict()** will get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Both the dictionary in the list pointing to same object, Hence modifying one will will change others also

```
>>> list_of_dict = [{}]*2
>>> id(list_of_dict[0])
50030176
>>> id(list_of_dict[1])
50030176
```

When you created two empty dictionary by using `dict()`, `dict()` return different object every time

```
>>> d1 = dict()
>>> d2 = dict()
>>> id(d1)
50074656
>>> id(d2)
50074512
```

Comment: This answer makes it seem like the choice of `dict()` in the second example is relevant. It isn't. `d1 = {}` and `d2 = {}` would have the same result as using `dict()`, it's *multiplying* a `list` containing just one `dict` that causes the problem.